# Subscripted Value is not an array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I am trying to assign the first 30 temperatures to the `June` array, the next 30 to the `July` array, and the last 30 to the `August` array. And for some reason, it is telling me that `fin >> temp[June]`; is "Subscripted Value is not an array." I know I am missing something but I'm stuck nonetheless. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    string file_name;
    int June[30];
    int July[30];
    int August[30];
    int temp;
    string date;
    const int days = 30;
    string firstline;

    cout << "please enter the file name" << endl;
    cin >> file_name;

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(file_name);

    if (fin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Failed to open " << file_name << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    getline(fin, firstline);
    for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
        fin >> date;
        fin >> temp[June];
        for (int j = 0; j < days; j++)
            fin >> date;
            fin >> temp[July];
            for (int k = 0; k < days; k++)
                fin >> date;
                fin >> temp[August];

    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should be `fin >> June[i];` if in your file all the temperature are listed. BTW, july and august have 31 days.

Comment: I don't see temp initialized anywhere ?

Comment: What is `temp` supposed to be? I think you meant to say `June[i]` etc?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your "Subscripted Value is not an array" error.

Anyway, I see some problems in your code that can be connected (or not).

(1) as observed by kkk, you use `temp`

```
fin >> temp[June];

uninitialized
```

(2) looking your code, I suspect your a Python programmer because your `for` are indented suggesting that is the indentation that determine the scope of the cycle. I mean... when you write

```
        for (int k = 0; k < days; k++)
            fin >> date;
            fin >> temp[August];
```

I suspect that you think that the cycle from zero to `days-1` is executed over both `fin >> date` and `fin >> temp[August]`.

Wrong.

In C/C++ the body of a `for` is the following statement (only `fin >> date`) and if you want more statement in the body, you have to include they between `{ }`.

So I suspect that your intention was

```
for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
 {
    fin >> date;
    fin >> temp[June];
 }

for (int j = 0; j < days; j++)
 {
    fin >> date;
    fin >> temp[July];
 }

for (int k = 0; k < days; k++)
 {
    fin >> date;
    fin >> temp[August];
 }
```

(3) the operator `a[b]`, in C (and in C++ for pointers and old C+style arrays), is syntactic sugar for (is defined as) `*(a+b)`.

So, if `June` is an array, you can write indifferently `June[0]` or `0[June]`. But usually is used the form `June[0]` and the form `0[June]` is an elegant (IMHO) form of obfuscation coding. A dangerous form, because when a class define an `operator[]`, the equivalence is lost and only the first form ins available.

So your

```
fin >> temp[June];
```

is technically correct (as far I know and excluding the fact that `temp` is uninitialized), but I suggest you to write

```
fin >> June[temp];
```

or presumably (as observed by bob__)

```
fin >> June[i]
```